# Javascript's assignment operation is to copy references?

Tags: javascript, reference, variable-assignment

The basic example:

```
var b = 10;
var c = b;
b++;
console.log(b,c);

>> 11 10
```

`c` looks like a copy of `b`.

But in another case:

```
var x = {};
var y = x;
x.abc = 10;
console.log(x.abc, y.abc);

>> 10 10
```

Why is the `y` not a copy of `x`, but a reference which points to the same instance `x` points to?

Also, I guessed `b++` creates another instance, so `b` points to the new instance but `c` points to the old one. However...

```
var u = 10;
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(u);
}, 10000)
u++;

>> 11
```

If `u++` creates a new instance, then the `u` inside the anonymous function should point to the old `u`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> the `c` looks like a copy of `b`.

Both are references to the same immutable value.

> Why the `y` is not copy of `x`  but a reference which points to the instance `x` points to?

`x` was a reference to an object in the first place, so `y` is a copy of it (a copy of the reference, not a copy of the object).

> If `u++` creates a new instance,

It doesn't.

> the `u` in anonymous function should points to the old `u`, shouldn't it?

`u++` assigns a reference to 11 to `u`. The anonymous function is looking at `u` and not "the value of `u` at the time the function was created".

Comment: @Quentin: so the original "object" just resides somewhere within the 'activation object' or 'lexical environment' created by the js-implementation (ES3/5) and can never really get touched by ECMAscript itself.

Comment: "Both are references to the same immutable value." Doesn't that contradict the observed output "11 10"? The output would suggest that they are references to different values

Comment: @Neptilo — No. Read the bottom half of the answer.

Comment: @Quentin So did you mean `b` and `c` are references to the same value *before* executing `b++`? But after, `b` becomes a reference to another value, right?

Comment: @Neptilo — Yes.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. That's what got me confused

Comment: "Both are references to the same immutable value." - this is what others refer as "assigned by value".

Answer (score 12):

When primitives are assigned, they are assigned **by value**; references types (like your object) are assigned **by reference** (or, as Jon Skeet corrects me, they're assigned a copy of the reference).

In your second example x and y both *point to* the same object in memory. That's why adding an `abc` property to one, also adds it to the other

You'd also observe the same behavior passing x or y into a function

```
function addABC(foo) {
   foo.abc = 10;
}

var x = {};
var y = x;
addABC(x);
console.log(x.abc, y.abc);
```

Just note that, though x and y point to the same object in memory, they're separate copies of the reference, so this

```
    var x = { a: 1 };
    var y = x;
    y = {};
    alert(x.a);
```

and this

```
    var x = { a: 1 };
    var y = x;
    x = {};
    alert(y.a);
```

will still alert 1.

Comment: I don't like the terminology of "by reference" here - because *real" pass-by-reference or copy-by-reference is somewhat different. For example, suppose you changed your `addABC` method to `foo = "hello"`, that wouldn't change the value of `x`, would it? (Admittedly I'm *assuming* that JavaScript works the same way as Java and C# here, but I think it's a reasonable assumption.)

Answer (score 5):

This statement:

```
var y = x;
```

copies the value of `x` as the initial value of `y`. However, the values involved are *references* to an object, not the object itself. Note that this is *not* the same as saying that the assignment copies "a reference to `x`" - it really is the *value* of `x`. So in particular, if you change the value of `x` to refer to a different object, e.g.

```
x = "something else";
```

then that won't change the value of `y` - its value will still be a reference to the original object.

Comment: Jon Skeet?!?!  In the JavaScript tag?!?!  Welcome, fine sir!

Comment: @AdamRackis: He's dipped his toe in this pond before.

Answer (score 0):

- The typeof value assigned to a variable decides whether the value is stored with assign-by-value or assign-by-reference
- On variable assignment, the scalar primitive values (Number, String, Boolean, undefined, null, Symbol) are assigned-by-value and compound values (Object, Array) are assigned-by-reference

If there are doubts look into this its explained with examples 
Link:
[how references work](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600)