# Object property-value behavior in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

In the below code, how is objA.foo value is set to 'bar'? (No-vice Javascript developer). Which concept or  functionality in JS sets the value of objA property to 'bar'?

```
var objA = Object.create({
    foo: 'foo'
});
var objB = objA;
objB.foo = 'bar';
console.log(objA.foo);
console.log(objB.foo);
```

Comment: Simply the fact that `var objB = objA;` doesn’t create a copy of the object. See [Javascript's assignment operation is to copy references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8792401/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var objB = objA` does not create a copy of the object. It holds a reference to `objA`. Modifying the object through the reference changes it for both variables holding a reference to that object.

To clone the Object, you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`.

```js
var objA = Object.create({
    foo: 'foo'
});
var objB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objA));
objB.foo = 'bar';
console.log(objA.foo);
console.log(objB.foo);
```

You can also use `Object.assign({}, obj)`.

```js
var objA = Object.create({
    foo: 'foo'
});
var objB = Object.assign({}, objA);
objB.foo = 'bar';
console.log(objA.foo);
console.log(objB.foo);
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_Objects).

Comment: +1; see also [a good explanation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_Objects)

Comment: @JohnEllmore Thanks, I have edited my answer to incorporate the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> var objB = objA;

You're actually creating a reference to `objA`. If you'd like to copy the object without a reference you can use the spread syntax:

```
var objB = {...objA};
```

Also, see: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @Xufox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Specifications

Comment: Yes, what about this specification table? Spread syntax has been around since ES6 for _arrays, arguments and parameters_, not for objects. [_Object_ spread](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-object_rest/spread_properties) has only been specified in ES 2018, which is ES9.

Comment: You're correct the MDN doc is missing the explicit reference to the addition of object spread in ES9 in their table. I'll forward your concerns to them.