# Backup worksheets in js, delete all and finally restore it

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Currently I'm triying to find a solution that helps me to storage the content of the worksheets in some place like localstorage for example.

```
async backupSheets() {
 await Excel.run(async (context) => {
  var worksheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
  worksheets.load('items');
  await context.sync();
  let wsBackup = worksheets;
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
    console.log(worksheets.items[i].toJSON());
    worksheets.items[i].delete();
  }
  //There will be some code to restore the workshets currently with:
  worksheets = wsBackup;
  //But it doesn't works.

  await context.sync();
 });
}
```

The expected behavior is when I do the assigment `worksheets = wsBackup` it restore the worksheets that I saved before the delete loop.
Currently this isn't working and I'm triying to find a workaround for this.

An Excel scenario should be..

- Copy all the worksheets in a variable called `wsBackup`
- Delete all worksheets except the last
- The proxy object that I used for it should be restored with the assigment of the backup `wsBackup`
- The worksheets should be restored properly in the workbook

The actual behavior that I got is all the steps except the restored worksheets.

Comment: Please provide more information about what goes wrong. What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: I've done the update. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a JavaScript object to another variable, you are assigning-by-reference, not assigning-by-value. So both `worksheets` and `wsbackup` are pointing to the same object in memory. When you delete the members of the `worksheets.items` property, you are also deleting the members of the `wsbackup.items` property, since `worksheets` and `wsbackup` are the same object. See this Stack answer for more: [JavaScript's assignment operation is to copy references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792401/javascripts-assignment-operation-is-to-copy-references).

Try replacing the line `let wsBackup = worksheets;` with the lines:

```
let wsbackup = context.workbook.worksheets;
wsbackup.load('items');
```

These lines will create an entirely new proxy object and load it's items.

Comment: That's why I love this line, though I'm sure there are edge cases it doesn't work. `let newobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: I don't think that that line would work if `obj` has methods as well as properties, as would be the case with `worksheets`.

Comment: yup, I use it purely for Obj's I made that are generally generic.